# How to configure slf4j with runjettyrun plugin on java Servlet?

Tags: logging, slf4j

I am looking to perform logging in my servlet, my server is a simple runjettyrun server plugin along with eclipse i am using SLF4J for logging

I am unable to get any logs, I have a doubt in setting the configurations

I am using the following code as per the documentation manual of slf4j

I have imported

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestHandler.class);
logger.debug(""+Now()+temp);
```

and this import has been done succesfully, but I don't not clearly know how to set the properties file for this, I read some where it should be configured using logback.xml and I am not clear about this, after reading the manual in slf4j website manual, can anyone kindly share some light?

Comment: how to override the default java.util.logging ? or it is not necessary? and also should i specify any dependencies?